# Coffeescript not completing but no error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I've having trouble with the following coffeescript:

```
jQuery ->
    # Create a comment
    $(".comment-form")
        .on "ajax:beforeSend", (evt, xhr, settings) ->
            $(this).find('textarea')
                .addClass('uneditable-input')
                .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            .on "ajax:success", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
                $(this).find('textarea')
                    .removeClass('uneditable-input')
                    .removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled')
                    .val('');
                $(xhr.responseText).hide().insertAfter($(this)).show('slow')

    # Delete a comment
    $(document)
        .on "ajax:beforeSend", ".comment", ->
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5)
        .on "ajax:success", ".comment", ->
            $(this).hide('fast')
        .on "ajax:error", ".comment", ->
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1)
```

Basically, I have a user form that I add comments to. When a new comment is added it should change class and disable the textarea before sending the data off to the database. Then it should reset the class, clear the textarea and enable the textarea again. Then finally it should add the new comment after the textarea.

The first part of the code works and the class is added to the textarea and it is set to disabled but the rest of the script never happens. Of course the comment is actually saved to the database and a refresh of the page will show the comment.

I've gone over this a ton of times and can't figure out what is going wrong. I did have an [earlier issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957855/cant-find-reason-why-xhr-is-not-defined?noredirect=1#comment33269274_21957855) with the indenting being wrong with the script but that has been fixed.

My CommentController code is as below:

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :destroy]

      def create
        @comment_hash = comment_params
        @obj = @comment_hash[:commentable_type].constantize.find(@comment_hash[:commentable_id])
        # Not implemented: check to see whether the user has permission to create a comment on this object
        @comment = Comment.build_from(@obj, current_user, @comment_hash[:body])
        @comment.user = current_user
        if @comment.save
          render partial: "comments/comment", locals: { comment: @comment }, layout: false, status: :created
        else
          p @comment.errors
          render js: "alert('error saving comment');"
        end
      end

      def destroy
        if @comment.destroy
          render json: @comment, status: :ok
        else
          render js: "alert('error deleting comment');"
        end
      end

      private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit( :commentable_id, :commentable_type, :body, :user_id)
    end

  end
```

Here's my form for creating comments:

```
<div class='comment-form'>
    <%= simple_form_for comment, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :body, input_html: { rows: "2" }, label: false %>
    <%= f.input :commentable_id, as: :hidden, value: comment.commentable_id %>
    <%= f.input :commentable_type, as: :hidden, value: comment.commentable_type %>
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Save Note', class: "button tiny radius", disable_with: "Submitting…" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And here's my code for displaying comments:

```
 <div class='comment'>
        <hr>
        <%=link_to "×", comment_path(comment), method: :delete, remote: true, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to remove this comment?',disable_with: 'x' }, class: 'close' %>
        <small><%=comment.updated_at.to_s(:short) %></small>
        <p><%= comment.body %></p>
```

By the way, the delete action partially works. It deletes the comment from the database and it hides all of the comments. A page refresh shows the comments that have not been deleted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I don't know where to go with this not at all. In my mind it should work so I must be missing something simple.

Comment: Why do you have semicolons in your Coffee code? In latest Coffeescript you can write your code much more idiomatic https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/077b1271014d1a039afb.

Comment: Also, I think you may have an issue with your identation, what's that `.on "ajax:success"` binding to? See my edit to the gist...

Comment: Yep that was it. Totally missed the indentation. Thanks for helping this coffeescript noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with your indentation. The line `.on "ajax:success"` must be indented at the same level as the other `.on`. And the code that follows must be indented accordingly as well:

```
jQuery ->
    # Create a comment
    $(".comment-form")
        .on "ajax:beforeSend", (evt, xhr, settings) ->
            $(this).find('textarea')
                .addClass('uneditable-input')
                .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        .on "ajax:success", (evt, data, status, xhr) -> #<-- this line!
            $(this).find('textarea')
                .removeClass('uneditable-input')
                .removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled')
                .val('');
            $(xhr.responseText).hide().insertAfter($(this)).show('slow')
```